# Publish Android App option in disabled in Xamarin using Visual studio 2015

Tags: android, publish, visual-studio-2015, xamarin-studio

When trying to publish my android application, the option: Tools->Android->Publish Android  App  is disabled in Visual studio 2015, so I am unable to sign my application and publish it.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Your question would illicit more responses if it included more information about what you're trying to accomplish as well as what you've already tried.

Answer (score 9):

go to properties of your project and uncheck the "Use Shared Runtime"
then `ctrl+shift +B`

Answer (score 8):

3 probable causes:

1- Your **Solution configuration** is on **Debug**, and you must select **Release** to deploy.

2- Uncheck **Use Shared Runtime** checkbox. When this is selected and you're in release mode, and the export option won't be available at all.

[image: Use shared runtime must be unchecked]

3- You deployed a previuos version and not changed yet the Android Manifiest file. To change choose your Droid project, open properties and check into **Android Manifiest** tab:

**Version Number** and **Version name** fields.

[image: Android manifiest]

Are same values of your previous deploy?

Try changing these values.

Seems like Xamarin will disable this option until you change it to new values.

Comment: I would also add as possible cause the "uncheck"  'Use Shared Runtime' checkbox. When this is selected and you're in releasemode, the export option won't be available at all.

Comment: I am having the same issue, and the options above didn't help.  Any more ideas on how to get that export option enabled once again (it was previously available)?

Comment: Hi @Jay, what version of Xamarin/VS do you have?. With the latest version the publishing process is a bit different, check this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_3_-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason, from Xamarin Forum (this fixed the issue for me). In Android-SDK>Tools I had a couple of folders only.

> SDK>Tools folder will be empty.  Go to SDK > Temp folder. There will
>   be a wrar named tools_. Copy this rar somewhere else and extract it.
>   Extracted folder will have the "Tools" folder. Replace this Tools
>   folder with SDK>Tools folder and Archive/SDK Manager etc everything
>   will be back.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85853/archive-option-is-disabled-in-visual-studio-2015

Then restart Visual Studio.