# Xamarin: Publish Android Application is missing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I don't have `Publish Android application` menu, and I have tried all `solution configurations`, including `Release`, and `AppStore`. I have also tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35041323/3967440) suggestions.

I'm using `Visual Studio 2015.3`, and `Xamarin 4.2`. I haven't bought any license though, but I think `Xamarin` is free?

[image]

I do have the `archive` option however, it can produce the `APK` it just doesn't accept my google play license file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It change to using Archive Manager, right click your android project and select Archive or from menu [Tools]  > [Archive Manager]

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/