# Archive function/option grayed out in Xamarin Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, archive

I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015. Recently I updated to sp3.

Now I want to publish my android app. From information elsewhere I understood that now this is supposed to be done by the function/option "Archive" available
by right-clicking the project or under the option/menu "Build".

However this option is grayed out for me, just as the function/option "View Archives". This is the case for all my android projects.

I already tried out/made sure of the things mentioned in the second answer of the older similar question.

[Publish Android App option in disabled in Xamarin using Visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855047/publish-android-app-option-in-disabled-in-xamarin-using-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: That's odd. That option is not greyed out on my end even if I have debug and shared mono runtime option selected.  You might try re-installing Xamarin for Visual Studio, maybe the vs update somehow corrupted the Xamarin install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by deciding it was a good time to do a total Windows 10 refresh (and thus doing a fresh visual studio 2015 install as well). This solved a lot other issues I had with my computer/visual studio as well. By lack of better I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you fixed your issue long ago but hope this will help anyone with the same problem.

Some info from Xamarin Forum, this fixed the issue for me. In SDK>Tools I had a couple of folders only.

> SDK>Tools folder will be empty.  Go to SDK > Temp folder. There will
>   be a wrar named tools_. Copy this wrar somewhere else and extract it.
>   Extracted folder will have the "Tools" folder. Replace this Tools
>   folder with SDK>Tools folder and Archive/SDK Manager etc everything
>   will be back.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85853/archive-option-is-disabled-in-visual-studio-2015

Then restart Visual Studio.

When you reinstalled Windows, you fixed the issue because you needed to reinstal Android SDK afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I performed a 'clean' on the project, closed all instances of VS and reloaded. The option then became available. Experienced this with VS2022.

Sorry, short and sweet, but hopefully useful!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the Release Mode and the click `Unload Project` and then `Reload Project`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my instance of this problem by right-clicking the Android project and choosing "Migrate to AndroidX".

I had manually updated to the latest version of Xamarin from an old version. I made all the changes to work on AndroidX manually and the app was running fine in debug mode.

I'm guessing the "migrate" command changed some configuration that I had missed. Even reloading the project hadn't enabled the "Archive..." option.